# Insert separator (blank line) in databound flowdocument

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, flowdocument

In my MVVM WPF application I'm using a databound flowdocument. I used the technique described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569761.aspx) to be able bind my data to the flowdocument.
My flowdocument is bound to a public property in my viewmodel. The property is an ienumerable of a custom type, like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Persons
{
    get { return _persons; }
    set { _persons = value; }
}
```

The flowdocument is shown in a FlowDocumentScrollViewer control. The document looks like:

```
code    name    lastname
----    -----   ---------
1       john    johnson
1       peter   peterson
2       jane    jane
3       john    doe
```

The binding works fine however I want to add a blank line after each distinct code:

```
code    name    lastname
----    -----   ---------
1       john    johnson
1       peter   peterson

2       jane    jane

3       john    doe
```

My Xaml in the view is:

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
  <FlowDocument>
    <flowdoc:ItemsContent ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons}">
      <flowdoc:ItemsContent.ItemsPanel>
        <DataTemplate>
          <flowdoc:Fragment>
            <Table BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
              <TableRowGroup flowdoc:Attached.IsItemsHost="True">
                <TableRow Background="LightBlue">
                  <TableCell>
                   <Paragraph>ronde</Paragraph>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <Paragraph>hal</Paragraph>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <Paragraph>datum</Paragraph>
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableRowGroup>
        </Table>
      </flowdoc:Fragment>
    </DataTemplate>
  </flowdoc:ItemsContent.ItemsPanel>
  <flowdoc:ItemsContent.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <flowdoc:Fragment>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell>
            <Paragraph>
              <flowdoc:BindableRun BoundText="{Binding Path=Code}" />
            </Paragraph>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell>
            <Paragraph>
              <flowdoc:BindableRun BoundText="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </Paragraph>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell>
            <Paragraph>
              <flowdoc:BindableRun BoundText="{Binding Path=LastName}" />
            </Paragraph>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </flowdoc:Fragment>
    </DataTemplate>
  </flowdoc:ItemsContent.ItemTemplate>
</flowdoc:ItemsContent>
```

Any suggestions on how to do this without breaking the MVVM rules? It seems like databinding a flowdocument comes with the price of inflexible layout.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the link you mentioned should be [Create Flexible UIs With Flow Documents And Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569761.aspx).

Comment: Yes, you're right. That is the correct link. I just corrected the link above. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to group your data, use a `CollectionViewSource` like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="groupView" Source="{Binding Path=Persons}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Code"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
        <FlowDocument>
            <flowdoc:ItemsContent ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupView}}">
               ....
            </flowdoc:ItemsContent>
        </FlowDocument>
    </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The `CollectionViewSource` element above sorts the `Persons` list by code and determines the groups.

Furthermore, you must adapt the `ItemsContent` class, because the one from the MSDN article does not yet support grouping. Here is a very simple example how you could achieve that:

```cs
private void GenerateContent(DataTemplate itemsPanel, DataTemplate itemTemplate, IEnumerable itemsSource)
{
    Blocks.Clear();
    if (itemTemplate != null && itemsSource != null)
    {
        FrameworkContentElement panel = null;

        if (panel == null)
        {
            if (itemsPanel == null)
            {
                panel = this;
            }
            else
            {
                FrameworkContentElement p = Helpers.LoadDataTemplate(itemsPanel);
                if (!(p is Block))
                {
                    throw new Exception("ItemsPanel must be a block element");
                }
                Blocks.Add((Block)p);
                panel = Attached.GetItemsHost(p);
                if (panel == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("ItemsHost not found. Did you forget to specify Attached.IsItemsHost?");
                }
            }
        }

        // *** START NEW CODE ***
        ICollectionView view = itemsSource as ICollectionView;
        if (view != null)
        {
            foreach (object group in view.Groups)
            {
                GenerateContentForUngroupedItems(itemsPanel, itemTemplate, ((CollectionViewGroup)group).Items, panel);
                if (panel is TableRowGroup)
                {
                    TableRow row = new TableRow();
                    row.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                    ((TableRowGroup)panel).Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            GenerateContentForUngroupedItems(itemsPanel, itemTemplate, itemsSource, panel);
        }
        // *** END NEW CODE ***
    }
}

private void GenerateContentForUngroupedItems(DataTemplate itemsPanel, DataTemplate itemTemplate,
                                                IEnumerable itemsSource, FrameworkContentElement panel)
{
    foreach (object data in itemsSource)
    {
        FrameworkContentElement element = Helpers.LoadDataTemplate(itemTemplate);
        element.DataContext = data;
        Helpers.UnFixupDataContext(element);
        if (panel is Section)
        {
            ((Section) panel).Blocks.Add(Helpers.ConvertToBlock(data, element));
        }
        else if (panel is TableRowGroup)
        {
            ((TableRowGroup) panel).Rows.Add((TableRow) element);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Don't know how to add an instance of {0} to an instance of {1}",
                element.GetType(), panel.GetType()));
        }
    }
}
```

Most of the code above is from the original MSDN article; the only changes I made are these:

- Moved the `foreach` loop to the new method `GenerateContentForUngroupedItems`.
- Moved the panel creation code ("`if (panel==null)`") outside the loop.
- Added the code marked `NEW CODE`.

What the modified code does is this: if the items source is not a collection view, it works exactly like the original MSDN code. If the items source is a collection view, two nested loops are called:

- The outer loop iterates over all groups.
- The inner loop iterates over all items in the current group.

The inner loop effectively is the same as the original foreach loop from the MSDN article.

In the added code above, the empty table row is added by these lines:

```cs
TableRow row = new TableRow();
row.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
((TableRowGroup)panel).Rows.Add(row);
```

This code, of course, is not very generic. For a generic solution, add a new dependency property to the `ItemsContent` control which contains a data template, just like the `ItemsPanel` or `ItemTemplate` properties. Then, you have the possibility to insert arbitrary text at the end of the group.

The result looks like this:

[image: Grouped flow document]

Comment: Hi, sorry dor the delay in my reply. Thank you very much for the solution and the clear and full explanation. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is grouping.  It stays within the MVVM rules.

Having said that, a quick google for grouping on flowdocuments didnt immediately show me anything.  Maybe have a look around for flowdocument wpf grouping.

One solution may be to use a datagrid.  you can definitely group on that with mvvm and make it look like the layout you have described above.